# How to set audioSession category for iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

How does one access the old API for setting audioSession categories? I have an old iPad that I use a video app on that is stuck at iOS 9.3. I'm using Xcode 10. I think it's just method i need here but I'm not sure how to find it.

```
func configureAudioSession() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .moviePlayback, options: .allowBluetooth)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: check this: http://www.openradar.me/42382075,   hope Apple will fix this in the next release.

Comment: Seriously. This is what I'm wondering too. Time to go back to ObjC?

Answer (score -3):

My solution is as follows:

First I write an OC class with method `setAudioCategory`, which set the `AVAudioSession` category to `setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`, and then call this method from Swift.

```
(void) setAudioCategory{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
}
```